# How to get the next next element in array in RISC-V?

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

Instead of incrementing by 4 bytes each time, would I need to increment by 8 bytes? Like for example, `addi x9, x9, 8` instead of `addi x9, x9, 4` ? Or would we need to consider the size of each word itself?

Comment: You increment by the element size, whatever that is.  e.g. 4 bytes for `int32_t`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok so for ```int32_t``` if I wanted the int 2 elements away, it would increment by 8 bytes then?

Comment: Yup, look at C compiler output on https://godbolt.org/ for a simple loop or something over an `int *arr` function arg if you want examples.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)